# dynamically generating tabular columns

Tags: tables, loops

Consider a table (regular tabular environment) with a fixed number of columns. I want to create a command that accepts a comma-separated list of strings, where the number of strings may differ between zero and the number of columns.

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \outputrow{ab cd,foo,3,5}\\ %all columns used
  \outputrow{}\\ %no column used
  \outputrow{1,2}\\ %two columns used
\end{tabular}
```

`\outputrow{cvs-input}` should, in all cases, generate all columns (4 in this example). The actual column value should be generated by two additional commands: `\emptycol` just outputs the content of an empty column, whereas `\usercol{content}` generates the corresponding output of the provided user input. So the result of the above example should be

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \usercol{ab cd} & \usercol{foo} & \usercol{3} & \usercol{5} \\
  \emptycol & \emptycol & \emptycol & \emptycol \\
  \usercol{1} & \usercol{2} & \emptycol & \emptycol \\
\end{tabular}
```

The number of columns is static for a single table, but I need this solution for different cases with a different number of columns.

I first thought of using a package like `etoolbox`, but I'm not sure how I can *emit* a single column using a loop or something like this.

Do you have any advice how this can be achieved?

Comment: Is `\emptycol` really necessary? For example, row 2 might just as well have been ``\\``.

Comment: One of your macros is named `\emptycol`, which at first glance would seem to indicate that it's supposed to generate an entire column. However, the code snippets you provide suggest that it's supposed to generate empty cells, not columns. Please clarify the purpose of this macro. Same goes for the name of `\usercol`.

Comment: @Werner yes, as it should generate a tikz picture

Comment: @Mico you are right, they don't generate a column but just a tikz picture that contains the user input string

Comment: You may want to rename the macros (col -> cell)

Comment: @Mico: Would the usage `\outputrow{<num>}{<csv>}`, where `<num>` denotes the number of columns, be appropriate?

Comment: @Werner yes, sure (I think you wanted to address me, didn't you?)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using some advanced TeX features, i.e. `\def` with a scantext instead of `\newcommand`. This way you can extract all text between the commas.

One way to do this would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\outputrow[1]{%
    \@outputrow#1,,,,,\@nil
}
\def\@outputrow#1,#2,#3,#4,#5\@nil{%
    \@usercol{#1} & \@usercol{#2} & \@usercol{#3} & \@usercol{#4} \\%
}
\def\@usercol#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@nnil\unexpanded{#1}\@nnil
        \emptycol
    \else
        \usercol{#1}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\usercol[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand\emptycol{(empty)}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \outputrow{ab cd,foo,3,5}\\ %all columns used
  \outputrow{}\\ %no column used
  \outputrow{1,2}\\ %two columns used
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

The `\outputrow` calls an internal macro `\@outputrow` and places the argument behind it without `{ }` but with several commas and an endmarker (`\@nil`). Then `\@outputrow` scans for the four arguments and consumes the remaining commas as fives argument which is then discarded. The four arguments as used with `\@usercol` which checks if the argument is empty and then uses `\emptycol` or `\usercol{#1}`.

Note that this can be improved as well, e.g. with a loop so it works with an large number of columns.